# Babel Automatic runtime for react doesnt working properly . Still getting Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, babeljs

according to new versions of React, we shouldn't always `import React from 'react'`
But I still have an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

.babelrc (Switching an order of presets doesnt help, removing some of presets too)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

pakage.json

```
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your ".babelrc" file into ".config.babel.js"

Then inside this file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ['@babel/preset-react', {runtime: 'automatic'}],
  ],
};
```

Using this file format enables the possibility for you to easily ignore files that you don't want to be transpilled using the property "transformIgnorePatterns" inside of your "package.json" file.

I personally use it with jest while testing react apps to prevent a few packages to be transpilled like so:

```
  "jest": {
    // [...]
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!react-bootstrap|bootstrap)"
    ]
    // [...]
  }
```

Hopefully, it will help some people.